# Skipping some lines based on their length in Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file which contains a lot of documents, how can i skip those lines that have length <= 2, and then process lines with length > 2. 
for example:

```
fit perfectly clie .
purchased not
instructions install helpful . improvement battery life not hoped .
product.
cable good not work . cable extremely hot not recognize devices .
```

after skipping lines:

```
fit perfectly clie .
instructions install helpful . improvement battery life not hoped .
cable good not work . cable extremely hot not recognize devices .
```

my code:

```
 val Bi = text.map(sen=> sen.split(" ").sliding(2))
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: OK, so which course has an assignment about bigrams? This is clearly part of the same problem as several questions from other people...

Comment: I agree @Paul. I have answered few of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use filter:

```
> val text = sc.parallelize(Array("fit perfectly clie .",
                                "purchased not",
                                "instructions install helpful . improvement battery life not hoped .",
                                "product.",
                                "cable good not work . cable extremely hot not recognize devices ."))

> val result = text.filter{_.split(" ").size > 2}
> result.collect.foreach{println}

fit perfectly clie .
instructions install helpful . improvement battery life not hoped .
cable good not work . cable extremely hot not recognize devices .
```

From here, you can work with your data in their original form (i.e. not tokenized) after filtering. If you'd prefer to tokenize first, then you can do this:

```
text.map{_.split(" ")}.filter{_.size > 2}
```

So, finally, to tokenize, then filter, and then find bigrams with `sliding`, you'd use:

```
text.map{_.split(" ")}.filter{_.size > 2}.map{_.sliding(2)}
```

Comment: Also note that to examine your data in the REPL after this last command, it's useful to add `.toList` inside the last map after `sliding(2)` before `collect`ing.

Answer (score 2):

How about `flatMap`

```
text.flatMap(line=>{
  val tokenized = line.split(" ")
  if(tokenized.length > 2) Some(tokenized.sliding(2))
  else None
})
```

Comment: This should be `else None` (i.e. without parentheses) but otherwise I like the combination of mapping and filtering in a single operation. Any idea how this compares to `map` then `filter` with respect to performance?

Comment: @ohruunuruus Oops, thanks for the catch. As to performance. Spark would pipeline the map/filter into one task, so I think the biggest win would be readability. An upvote would be appreciated if you do like it :)

Comment: Yep, was just waiting for the fix before upvoting ;)